# Sequential loading of scripts in require.js and use.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using in my project require.js and it's plugin use.js.

```
require.config({
// Initialize the application with the main application file
deps: ["main"],

paths: {
    // JavaScript folders
    libs: "../assets/js/libs",
    plugins: "../assets/js/plugins",

    // Libraries
    jquery: "../assets/js/libs/jquery",
    underscore: "../assets/js/libs/underscore",
    backbone: "../assets/js/libs/backbone",
    jqueryUI: "../assets/js/libs/jqueryUI",
    jquerySlider: "../assets/js/libs/slider",
    jqueryMouseWheel: "../assets/js/libs/jquery.mousewheel",    
    jquerySelectBox: "../assets/js/libs/selectBox",
    jqueryMouse: "../assets/js/libs/mouse",
    bookReader: "../assets/js/libs/newReader",

    // Shim Plugin
    use: "../assets/js/plugins/use"
},

use: {
    backbone: {
        deps: ["use!underscore", "jquery"],
        attach: "Backbone"
    },

    underscore: {
        attach: "_"
    },

    jqueryUI: {
        deps: ["jquery"]
    },

    jquerySlider: {
        deps: ["jquery", "jqueryMouse"]
    },

    jquerySelectBox: {
        deps: ["jquery"]
    },

    jqueryMouse: {
        deps: ["jquery", "jqueryUI"]
    },

    jqueryMouseWheel: {
        deps: ["jquery", "jqueryUI"]
    },

    bookReader: {
        deps: ["jquery", "jqueryUI", "jqueryMouse", "jquerySlider", "jqueryMouseWheel", "jquerySelectBox"],
        attach: "Reader"
    }
}
});
```

The problem is that scripts start load simultaneously, and because of that there are unmet dependencies, often there are these two errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a, b) {return new e.fn.init (a, b, h)} has no method 'widget': 4444/assets/js/libs/mouse.js: 15
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouse' of undefined: 4444/assets/js/libs/slider.js: 20
```

Once the files are in the cache, the problem no longer occurs.
So, my question. How do I specify that the script must loaded consistently?

It is possible to build scripts that wrap them into one file. But this option is not very desirable

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this AMD loader plugin called STEP, it allows you to load scripts in sequential order.

https://github.com/requirejs/step

Comment: Its not clean on how to install step in requirejs. I tried to include step.js to be called before and after require.js but neither worked. any suggestions?